# Lazy Calculation result of bash functions in alias

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, alias

I want to open new terminal window in current location by simple command in Ubuntu

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=`pwd` & disown
```

Work's nice for me. But when I put alias to bashrc

```
alias clone="gnome-terminal --working-directory=`pwd` & disown "
```

`pwd` Calculated at start. So i get something like.

```
$ type clone
 clone is aliased to `gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/user & disown '
```

Is it possible make `pwd` calculate only when i call alias. Or I need to write bash function except alias?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use single quotes around the `alias` declaration command so that the command substitution (`pwd`) does not take place while declaring (and will expand only when the alias is called):

```
alias clone='gnome-terminal --working-directory=`pwd` & disown'
```

Also start using command substitution syntax `$()` instead of older and problematic ``` `` ```:

```
alias clone='gnome-terminal --working-directory="$(pwd)" & disown'
```

---

Also note that `gnome-terminal` is designed in such a manner that whenever you do

```
gnome-terminal
```

it would open a new window with the same PID as the original one. This is because its the same process by design, exiting one won't kill the other(s).  So you don't need the `disown` and backgrounding (`&`), just:

```
alias clone='gnome-terminal --working-directory="$(pwd)"'
```

would do.

Moreover, as pointed out by @Digital Trauma, `gnome-terminal` always starts off at current working directory, so `--working-directory` is not needed as you are setting it as `pwd`. So you can just do:

```
alias clone='gnome-terminal'
```